# Are user defined runtime attributes documented for iOS 5?

Tags: ios, xcode4, interface-builder

In the Identity Inspector of the interface editor in Xcode 4, there is a section titled "User Defined Runtime Attributes"

[image: User Defined Runtime Attributes]

Setting values here appears to work fine for iOS 5 and later, but I can find no documentation for this. If I use this, am I risking rejection for use of undocumented behavior? Is there Apple documentation that I am just unable to find?

Comment: What does Apple say?  Why would they put something in XCode, the use of which would invalidate your app?

Comment: My problem is that Apple doesn't say much at all. The feature was originally in XCode for Mac OSX apps, and certainly doesn't work for iOS 4 apps. Perhaps I'm just paranoid, but I would hate to invest heavily in the use of this feature, only to have Apple claim it as undocumented during the review.

Comment: I guess the problem I'm having with this question is that anyone could be paranoid about any feature in XCode that is similarly undocumented, and your question has little hope of getting answered unless an Apple employee happens to wander in here.

Comment: There was always the chance that I just hadn't figured out the right search terms to find the documentation on the feature. Having no answers here may just be confirmation that it is indeed undocumented and thus unsafe to rely upon.